# Converting Factor columns to Numeirc with missing values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 270 columns. Some of the columns are supposed to be numbers but they are encoded as strings. I am trying to convert a few columns (R sees them as factors) to numbers. There are also missing values in the factor columns.

The code I had written so far:

```
 temp[, c(19:263)][is.na(temp[, c(19:263)])] <- "0"

 temp[,c(19:263)] <-sapply(temp[,c(19:263)], as.numeric)
```

Running the fist line gives me 16 warnings and does not convert NAs to 0s

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
5: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
6: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
7: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
8: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
9: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
10: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
11: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
12: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
13: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
14: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
15: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
16: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

And the second code converts all 0s to 1s

Comment: Please check the `str` of the dataset.  It should be all `factor` (based on the error too.  Either you convert those columns to `character` or create a level with '0' before doing the assignment i.e. `temp[19:263] <- lapply(temp[19:263], as.character)` or do the assignment also here `temp[19:263] <- lapply(temp[19:263], function(x)  replace(as.character(x), is.na(x), 0))`

Comment: str shows that all the columns are factors. I was under the impression that factors and characters are same.

Comment: If we need to keep it as `factor` columns `temp[19:263] <- lapply(temp[19:263], function(x) {levels(x) <- c(levels(x), '0'); replace(x, is.na(x), '0')})`

Comment: factors are useful for certain situations, but with data cleaning, transforming, it is better to have as `character` class

Comment: @akurn, I was able to do it using your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading the data from a csv? If so, if you specify stringsAsFactors = F as an argument to the read.csv function, it would not assume the strings to be factors.

As for the numeric part, you can use plyr colwise function where you basically use as.numeric as the function.

You can find more information with regards to colwise [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/colwise). Hope this helps!

Comment: from SAS Actually

Comment: Are you using the sas7bdat package to do so?

Comment: Haven actually. But I was able to convert the factors to characters. and then proceed